# android : unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just installed the latest Android Studio and I get the error in the title; I tried many solutions from the internet but nothing works.

So please can you help me to fix this?

I got this error:

```
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    ... 104 more Cause 5: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve **androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5**.
Required by:
    project :
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource '**https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.5/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.5.pom**'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET '**https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.5/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.5.pom'.**
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:130)
```

The project is the basic project sample in Android Studio.

Comment: If you visit https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.5/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.5.pom in a Web browser, does it download a POM file? If the answer is no, then something about your computer or ISP is preventing you from accessing Google's Maven artifact repository.

Comment: yes i can download the file from chrome i also tried vpn and nothing work

Comment: @martin-zeitler you closed this issue, but the issue you linked has nothing to do with OP's problem

Comment: @martin-zeitler the why you close this is not duplicate !!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing this in an enterprise environment. Are you using Artifactory? Seems like to me that you are missing certificates and that is why you can't connect.

Comment: i know i"m using my mobile network how i can solve this

Comment: Maybe your mobile network doesn't allow hotspot or you ran out of hotspot data and basically this is the error you get?

Comment: no is working on chrome and i can download file without problem the problem in android studio

Comment: Last time I saw this error the company I work for provided me certificates that I installed and everything worked just fine after.... So unfortunately can't help. Never seen this issue on my personal computer.